# Unable to set up Elasticsearch for Wagtail

Tags: python, linux, django, elasticsearch, wagtail

I used the following guide so far:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/advanced_topics/performance.html

I added:

```
WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'wagtail.wagtailsearch.backends.elasticsearch',
        'INDEX': '{{ project_name }}',
    },
}
```

to my base.py. When I run `$ ./manage.py update_index`, I get the following output:

```
Updating backend: default
default: Rebuilding index {{ project_name }}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/management/commands/update_index.py", line 120, in handle
    self.update_backend(backend_name, schema_only=options.get('schema_only', False))
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/management/commands/update_index.py", line 73, in update_backend
    index = rebuilder.start()
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/backends/elasticsearch.py", line 613, in start
    self.reset_index()
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/backends/elasticsearch.py", line 609, in reset_index
    self.index.reset()
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/backends/elasticsearch.py", line 598, in reset
    self.delete()
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/backends/elasticsearch.py", line 499, in delete
    self.es.indices.delete(self.name)
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 73, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/indices.py", line 200, in delete
    params=params)
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 318, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 123, in perform_request
    raise ConnectionError('N/A', str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3b708fa210>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3b708fa210>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT UPDATE:

It looks like my Linode might not have enough RAM. I get the following error when trying to run ES with ./bin/elasticsearch after global install:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000085330000, 2060255232, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 2060255232 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/emtr0/elasticsearch-5.3.0/hs_err_pid24719.log
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your Elasticsearch server isn't running. Please can you try the more detailed configuration instructions at http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/topics/search/backends.html#elasticsearch-backend ?

Comment: @gasman I will try that and get back to you ASAP.

Comment: @gasman Why does the page you shared show different information than the guide I was using? The directories are different. I don't have `wagtail/wagtail/wagtailsearch/backends/elasticsearch.py` anywhere. All the settings changes, including where to add the wagtailsearch snippet, need to be at the end of base.py, right?

Comment: @gasman I also tried allowed port 9200 per your docs link but that didn't work either. I recently redeployed the whole thing with python 3.6 but I'm getting the same error when trying to update the index. The snippet saves without error and I have it in my requirements.txt but update_index still produces the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment directly under your question, I hope this will help you to get things sorted out:

- install elasticsearch locally, run it, and then check if it's running (should be on port 9200) using a simple `curl http://localhost:9200`. If you get a JSON response, it's running

OR

- setup a bonsai (http://bonsai.io) instance in order to have a hosted elasticsearch server running, and just copy-paste the bonsai's server URL into your config, but it can need a bit more settings (SSL etc), and is more limited in term of elasticsearch version

Bonus: if you are a macOS user, installing/running Elastic Search is as easy as `brew install elasticsearch` (maybe set a specific version though), and then `elasticsearch` if you don't mind about having it running in the foreground.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I installed elasticsearch in a virtual environment using pip. The guides I used don't mention manually running the server. I later installed it system-wide but still can't find the command to run it.

Comment: How did you install it ? What operating system are you running it on ?

Comment: ElasticSearch python app is different than Elastic Search in itself. It should run, as a standalone app, alongside your django app. On a different port

Comment: I have it set up on a Linode with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. At first I followed the guide at http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/advanced_topics/performance.html and then after your reply, I installed it system-wide just in case. A bin wasn't created for it for some reason and it won't take start commands because a service wasn't associated with it.

Comment: Python app for elastic search is really different (even if installed globally). It is a client for an elastic search server. That can be running on your local machine, or on an external server. Did you follow these instructions in order to have a local elastic search server running ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-targz.html
Or if you are into docker, maybe try this one: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Comment: I'm running it just for the virtual env installation for wagtail. Could that be the problem?

Comment: ES is a Java app, it doesn't rely on a virtual env (that is python-specific). Did you follow my previous instructions ? 
As said before, elasticsearch app, as a python app is only a client, that accesses a separate Elastic Search server, running elsewhere (on your local machine, or on an external machine).

Answer (score 1):

For people still having issues with this, make sure your  Elasticsearch version and elasticsearch-py version are the same. Both elasticsearch and the py versions need to be installed. That fixed it for me.